# How to keep xmodmap after suspend

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xmodmap

I have an xmodmap file `~/.Xmodmap` and it works perfectly. I put it in the startup applications app in ubuntu 19.10 like this `xmodmap /home/yasser/.Xmodmap` and it works when first booting up. However, after suspend, the file just doesn't work. I tried creating a script in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/999zxmodmap` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

    case $1 in
        pre)
            exit 0
        ;;
        post)
            export DISPLAY=:0
            sleep 10
            xmodmap /home/yasser/.Xmodmap
        ;;
    esac
```

I saw this suggested somewhere else, but this didn't work. 
Here is my `~/.Xmodmap` file if that can help:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym j = j J Left
keysym l = l L Right
keysym i = i I Up
keysym k = k K Down
keysym h = h H Home
keysym semicolon = semicolon colon End
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line just after your `export DISPLAY=:0` line:

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/yasser/.Xauthority
```

When an X11 GUI session is started, `~/.Xmodmap` is automatically read as the user logging in.

But when `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/999zxmodmap` is executed after resuming from suspend, it is executed as root.

Like any X11 application, the `xmodmap` command needs two things to access the GUI session: the `DISPLAY` environment variable, and the *X11 session cookie* (= a key of sorts). By default, the session cookie is stored in `~/.Xauthority` and it is recreated on every X11 login. When your script runs the `xmodmap` command as root, it will look for the session cookie in `/root/.Xauthority`... which is not the right place to look if the currently logged-in user is `yasser`.

Fortunately, you can use the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable to tell X11 applications to find the session cookie in a non-standard location... and because root can access everything, the `xmodmap` command running as root will be able to read `yasser`'s cookie file.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't work as well. a question though, when I checked my home folder ` ~/.Xauthority` is not there, is that normal?

Comment: Your distribution might routinely place it in a non-default location: run `echo $XAUTHORITY` in a terminal window in your regular GUI session and then adjust the value in the script to match.

Comment: I found it in /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority and changed accordingly but still not working I don't understand why. anyways thanks for your help and if you have any other suggestion let me knnow please.